# OpenVPN on Ubuntu VPS Server lost connection

Tags: server, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to VPN from Ubuntu server (version 16.04), but when server establish connection I lost the connection with server, and server seem doesn't have connection too. As I cannot make tests when server connect to VPN I have prepared a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo openvpn --client --config /etc/openvpn/England.ovpn --auth-user-pass authVpn.txt &
sleep 10
route > route.txt
curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address://' -e 's/&lt;.*$//' > ip.txt
ping www.google.es -c 4 > ping.txt
# Kill processes to can connect again
ps axf | grep "openvpn" | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sh
```

When I reconnect, **ip.txt** and **ping.txt are empty**. The content of **route.txt** is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.127.0.97     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         164.132.192.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
10.127.0.1      10.127.0.97     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.127.0.97     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
45.32.180.53    164.132.192.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ens3
128.0.0.0       10.127.0.97     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
164.132.192.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ens3
```

I have made the same test with Oracle VM on my computer and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problems:

1 - Server doesn't access to internet after connection with VPN. **Solution**: add Google DNS to /etc/resolv.conf (nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4)

2 - I cannot access to server after this connect with VPN. **Solution**: redirect the VPN traffic to real IP:

```
ip rule add from x.x.x.x table 128
ip route add table 128 to y.y.y.y/y dev ethX
ip route add table 128 default via z.z.z.z
```

Where x.x.x.x is your public IP, y.y.y.y/y should be the subnet of your public IP address, ethX should be your public Ethernet interface, and z.z.z.z should be the default gateway. Information obtained from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/659955/allowing-ssh-on-a-server-with-an-active-openvpn-client) and [here](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=50114&sid=d4e386790351a09f638cff7fdeaeee8a#p50114)